# Cordova Inapp Browser Execute JS Function

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have a java script function in my html page which I've opened in an Inapp Browser in my ionic app. I want to execute this custom java script funtion using executeScript().

So far I have tried following but no luck. Is there any other way to do so?

```
browser.on("savePressed").subscribe(val => {

    //SAVE_FORM() is java script function inside html page

    browser.executeScript({code: "SAVE_FORM()"}).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

    browser.close();
});
```

I'm using Themeable browser (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/themeable-browser/) in which I have a button. When I press save button `savePressed` function is executed. In that function I want to run `executeScript` function which is supposed to run `SAVE_FORM()` function which is present inside source code of html document which is opened in inApp Browser.

Comment: why `"SAVE_FORM()"` just try `SAVE_FORM()`

Comment: so this code runs on your i guess in index.html right? so why can't you just use a script tag and execute your function? isn't it working that way?

Comment: you are you opening the inAppBrowser? is SAVE_FORM() available in the web you are loading? what calls the savePressed event?

Comment: @jcesarmobile yes I'm opening in inAppBrowser, nothing happens, callback function doesn't get executed, neither do i get any error

Comment: sorry, the first *you* should be a *how*. I mean, show more code, that's not enough to see whats going on

Comment: Please check my edits in question

Comment: @casper123 did you get this working. I am facing the same issue